# sql to query columns with special character

Tags: mysql

my query is like

```
$insert_query = "insert into post (post_title) values ('$post_title')";
```

If my post_title = Ronald's bio-data, I would not be able to insert the tuple because of the special character ' in my post_title.

How should solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: if i will give you solution you can store special char also DB Then ?

Comment: I think your problem is you unable to store value or you do not want to store

Answer (score 3):

Use *Prepared Statements* to escape parameters automatically in your queries

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into post (post_title) values (?)";
$stmt->bindParam(1, $post_title);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what is $dbh?

Comment: `$dbh` is the DB handler. [here is a good quick tutorial](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `$mysqli->real_escape_string(String)` function.

```
$post_title = $mysqli->real_escape_string($post_title);
$insert_query = "insert into post (post_title) values ('$post_title')";
```

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for more information.

Note that using variables in SQL Strings always emits a potential vulnerability due to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for alternatives.